# Как удалить ненужные пробелы и скобки из ячеек столбца

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Уже знакомая таблица и вопрос:

|  | name |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | ('mike, rick, morty' ) |
| 1 | ( 'tot, piter, carl') |

Как удалить ненужные скобки и пробелы? Нужен такой результат:

|  | name |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | mike, rick, morty |
| 1 | tot, piter, carl |

Код, образующий таблицу (изменения нужны в cтолбце gr):

```
d = {'name': ['mike, rick, morty', 'tot, piter, carl', 'brick, nick', 'rick, reaven, bart, homer', 'rick, morty'], 'Date': ['11/05/2011', '9/02/2010', '1/01/2014', '12/20/2020', '9/30/2009'], 'Address': ['AR', 'YU', 'RU', 'EU', 'BY']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data = d)
df['name1'] = df.name.str.split(',')
df['gr'] = df.name.apply(lambda x: list(combinations(df['name1'][df.index[df["name"].eq(x)][0]], 2)))
df = df.explode('gr')
display(df)
```

Comment: А как вы получили такие значения?

Comment: А вы пробуете что-то искать, прежде чем задавать вопросы?

Comment: Когда функцией combinations разбил по парам и explode разбил на несколько  значений.

Comment: что показывает `print(type(df.at[0, "name"]))`?

Comment: <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

Comment: ну тогда без __воспроизводимого__ примера входных данных вам будет трудно помочь) PS я еще не видел чтобы Pandas.Series отображались в скобках...

Comment: Добавил в шапку

Comment: если я не ошибаюсь, то вот этот код `  df['gr'] = df.name.apply(lambda x: list(combinations(df['name1'][df.index[df["name"].eq(x)][0]], 2))) `  можно заменить на `  df['gr'] = df.name1.apply(lambda x: list(combinations(x, 2)))  `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас там во-первых кортежи лежат, поэтому и скобки, а во-вторых там лишний пробел тянется у элементов из-за пробела после запятой в исходной строке.

Лишние пробелы можно победить, добавив регулярку в `split`, означающую "0 или более пробелов":

```
df['name1'] = df.name.str.split(',\s*')
                                  ^^^
```

А превратить кортежи в строки можно с помощью `str.join`, в самом конце кода добавив строку:

```
df['gr'] = df.gr.str.join(',')
```

Столбец `gr` после этого будет выглядеть так:

```
        gr
 mike,rick
mike,morty
rick,morty
...
```

`split` и `join` - это как бы взаимно обратные операции, одна делит строку на коллекцию по определённому символу, а другая наоборот склеивает элементы коллекции в строку через указанный символ.